# log4net in .net core 2.0 console application

Tags: .net-core, console-application, log4net, .net-core-2.0

When using `log4net` from `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore` `2.2.4` running

```
dotnet publish -c release -r win81-x64
```

causes these errors:

```
:: error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Net.NameResolution from 4.3.0 to 4.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
:: error NU1605:  DailyPieChartUpdate -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore 2.2.4 -> log4net 2.0.8 -> System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0 -> runtime.win.System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0 -> System.Net.NameResolution (>= 4.3.0)
:: error NU1605:  DailyPieChartUpdate -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore 2.2.4 -> log4net 2.0.8 -> System.Net.NameResolution (>= 4.0.0)
:: error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Net.Primitives from 4.3.0 to 4.0.11. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
:: error NU1605:  DailyPieChartUpdate -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore 2.2.4 -> log4net 2.0.8 -> System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0 -> runtime.win.System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0 -> System.Net.Primitives (>= 4.3.0)
:: error NU1605:  DailyPieChartUpdate -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore 2.2.4 -> log4net 2.0.8 -> System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0 -> System.Net.Primitives (>= 4.0.11)
  Restore failed in 588.96 ms
```

Any advice?

Comment: sounds like you need to update some of your packages

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 is to go into your project files and make sure you have references to only one version of log4net,
Step 2 is to clean your local nuget packages
Step 3 is to get all the nuget packages again

hopefully, that solves your problem

it is a good idea to reference the latest log4net version for .net core.

Comment: Did not help. when getting log4net Latest stable 2.0.8 from nuget, it also adds bunch of other packages the the publish has a problem with later.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm answering too much time later, but...

The problem I thought is caused because some of your already imported libraries on your project are downgrades of the imported libraries that Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore nuget are referencing.

There are other users that have problems with the same issue. You can check [this github issue](https://github.com/huorswords/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore/issues/43#issuecomment-407179121) to find out what is the solution.

Sorry by the inconveniences.